# Python getting past eval checking for variables?

Tags: python-3.x, encryption

I am making a cipher converter:

```
self.numberList = list(str(cipherText)))
```

`CipherText` is read from a `.dat (key = open('keyData.dat', 'r+'))` file. It's like this:

```
qK, zR
21,26
```

I want to turn `qK, zR` into `['qK', 'zR', 21, 26]`

How else can I do this without getting,

> `NameError: name 'qK' is not defined?`

In short; I want to read groups of letters and turn them into a list instead of single characters turned into a list so `['zX', 'xY']` and **not** `['z', 'X', '', 'q', 'K']`

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Can you try to clarify your question?

Comment: Why are you using `eval` at all? What did you expect `eval` to do for you?

Comment: Sounds like you want to look into the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.